# Scrolling outside RecyclerView first

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I need your help for a little issue.

**What I have:**

1. A NestedScrollView with a vertical LinearLayout inside of it.
2. Inside the LinearLayout, I have three elements : a CardView, a RecyclerView and another CardView.

**Current situation :**
If I set the RecyclerView Height to "wrap_content" it will calculate the size according to its content BUT, with 500 elements a bit complexe, it takes 7-8s so this solution is not valid.

**What I need:**

I think I need a solution where the RecyclerView would act like a list but charging the elements dynamically and not all in once.

**What I tried:**
I tried to set the RecyclerView Height to a fixed size bigger than a screen (let's say 1000dp) but it has 2 problems :

1. If there's not enough elements to fill the Recycler, there will be an empty space at the end of the Recycler.
2. If there are enough elements to fill the Recycler, when I scroll, it will first scroll the content of the Recycler and then, when it reached the end, scroll the NestedScrollView to display the last CardView.

Ideally, I would like it scrolls first the NestedScrollView until the top of the Recycler reaches the top of the NestedScrollView, THEN it scrolls the Recycler and finally, when reached the end of the Recycler, finishes to scroll the NestedScrollView until its end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you place overScrollMode in your RecyclerView. It will make sure it behaves properly in the NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Also loading 500+ elements all at once might take up memory, especially if it contains much data, I would suggest you paginate them and each time the RecyclerView reaches the first end "let's say 10 items" then it will proceed to retrieve more until it reaches all your items.